# Branding above navbar Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

It's been a long time since I've worked on any web projects and even longer since I've built something from scratch so I'm very new to CSS grid systems such as the one included in Bootstrap 3. I'm building a website and perhaps the largest part of the challenge is learning to think in terms of the mobile first grid system.

I'm working on a header that works in much the same way as the header on the [New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/) webzine or to put it descriptively it is fixed width, has a site branding (image) centred above a navbar on medium and large devices. Below medium the navbar collapses and moves to the same row as the branding (on the far-left) and the search icon moves to the far-right on the same row. So to visualise:

Medium/Large Devices:

```
    BRANDING
NAVBAR - SEARCH
```

Small/Extra Small Devices:

```
NAVBAR(COLLAPSED) - BRANDING - SEARCH
```

I'm not so much interested in having my hand held where the code is concerned, but a description of how that can be achieved using the B3 grid system.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox will be your bestfriend for this.

However for Bootsrap you can reorder columns using classes like .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* to shift a column to the right or left, respectively. This would become relevant in your media queries (pulling the brand column into the middle) to achieve what you're looking for :)

For an intro to Flexbox I recommend:

[https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/](http://CSS%20Tricks%20-%20Flexbox)

[http://flexbox.io/view/qWL-7ih9Kw0](http://Flexbox%20video%20tutorials)

For a great overview of the bootstrap grid system check this out:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/

Comment: Thank you for those links. Based off your mention of push and pull I found this page: [https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap](https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap).

I have a follow up question. In every example I've seen as the screen gets larger elements use up less columns. So we might have 2 columns with a width of 12 on mobile which reduces to 2 columns of 6 on larger screens. Is there any technicalities involved in the reverse. I.E. taking up less columns as width decreases?

Comment: You should design from the mobile Up. So in that sense your brand is maybe 2-8 columns (depending on what you want), and then when you move up in screen size, you make the order of the brand columns come FIRST, and then bump it up to 12 columns so that the other 2 elements then become "overflow" and spill into a new row. You would also then increase the overflow cols size to take up the space missing from where the brand was. This is how I would approach this problem . Of course I have not sat down to make this, and there may be things like styling issues with overflows etc.

Comment: Although, because it cannot be said enough, I recommend using flexbox. It really takes the headache out of these types of things. It also has an "order" property.

Comment: I managed to achieve the effect I wanted using push and pull. Flexbox is definitely something I should play around with in full. Thank you for your support.